# In MFC programs, what messages are sent when all the controls on the dialog box are drawn?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a dialog class derived from CDialogEx, with a square CStatic control on the dialog interface. I want the control to be initially displayed with a black background and a green diagonal line drawn on it.

I have rewritten the functions of the following two base classes, set the background color in OnCtlColor, and drew diagonal line in OnWindowPosChanged.

After running the program, the background color of the control successfully turned black, and the green diagonal was also drawn successfully. However, it is obvious that the diagonal is below the black background, even below the control (or that the drawing of the control overwrites the drawing of the diagonal because I tried to annotate the OnCtlColor function, and the diagonal is still blocked by the control).

I set breakpoints in both functions and found that the breakpoint in OnWindowPosChanged triggers before the breakpoint in OnCtlColor. So I guess the reason why the diagonal is covered by the control is because OnWindowPosChanged executes before OnCtlColor.

So I want to ask where the code should be written if I want to do something after a certain control in the dialog box is drawn (or the entire dialog box is drawn)?

```
HBRUSH CreateCutOffDitchDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{

    HBRUSH hbr = __super::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_CANVAS_PREVIEW)
    {
        hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        return hbr;
    }

    // TODO:  Return a different brush if the default is not desired
    return hbr;
}

void CreateCutOffDitchDlg::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS* wndpos)//test
{

    __super::OnWindowPosChanged(wndpos);
    if (wndpos->flags & SWP_SHOWWINDOW) {
        CRect r;
        canvasPreview->GetWindowRect(r);
        CDC* pDC = canvasPreview->GetDC();
        CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0, 255, 0));
        pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
        pDC->MoveTo(0, 0);
        pDC->LineTo(r.Width(), r.Height());
    }
}
```

In the above code, "canvasPreview" is the CStatic control, "IDC_CANVAS_PREVIEW" is the corresponding ID.

After running, the control displays as follows:

[image]

If the "ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()" macro of the mapping message is commented out, the diagonal is still obscured::

[image]

Comment: You cannot render into a window that's not yours. If you need custom rendering, either register a window class, or subclass an existing window class.

Comment: @IInspectable I think you can also implement an `OnPaint` handler and do the drawing there. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WM_CTLCOLOR` message (`OnCtlColor()`) is used in cases where you want to use different foreground or background colors for certain controls, using otherwise "standard" painting. Features like drawing a diagonal line over the control is custom drawing.  And of course doing this only when the window position is changed (becoming visible in this case) isn't OK. Your app should instead be handling the case of normal painting, that is when the window gets the client area or a part of it "invalidated" (as a result of hiding/unhiding, moving another window in front of it eg a dialog-box and then closing it, moving the parent window past the visible desktop area and then moving it back in, etc, or programmatically invalidating it). If a window contains an invalid area it will receive a `WM_PAINT` message just before the message-queue is about to get empty. Therefore you have to write a handler for the `WM_PAINT` message. You may want to take a look into [Painting and Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing).

There are three ways to do this in MFC:

1. Make the `IDC_CANVAS_PREVIEW` control owner-drawn. The parent window (dialog) will be getting calls to the `OnDrawItem()` member (`WM_DRAWITEM`), which you must override to perform the custom painting. Use the `HDC` member of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure to paint the control.
2. Define a `CStatic`-derived class and override the `DrawItem()` function, to perform the custom painting. Again, use the `HDC` member of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure to paint the control. Use VS's Class Wizard to associate the `IDC_CANVAS_PREVIEW` with an instance of your newly-defined class (Add a control variable). This "subclasses" the control.
3. Alternatively you may override the `OnPaint()` handler (`WM_PAINT`) in the new class. Use the `CDC*` arg to paint the control. It wraps a `HDC` for the control's client area, obtained by the MFC framework, calling the `BeginPaint()` function (don't call `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` yourself). The control doesn't need to be owner-drawn in this case.

The 1st method is the easiest to implement, because all you have to do is process the `WM_DRAWITEM` message (mapped to the `OnDrawItem()` member) of the parent dialog class, easily done using the resource editor (Properties->Messages). The other two require defining a new C++ class, but this code is reusable (in another dialog or project).

And finally a remark about your code, in **GDI** you normally have to destroy or release the objects you create, otherwise this results in leakages. For every create/get/select call there must be a destroy/release/select counterpart. For example, for the `GetDC()` call you should have called `ReleaseDC()` after you are done. And the pen selected into the DC should have been selected out of it before return - no need to explicitly destroy the pen you created because the `CPen` destructor will do it for you (but this is by MFC). The brush you created in `OnCtlColor()` should be destroyed as well, per the [WM_CTLCOLOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic) documentation. But as the brush must be returned, you cannot do this inside the function; the best approach for this would be to cache the brush handle, ie create it in the dialog's constructor, use it in every `OnCtlColor()` call (instead of creating it) and destroy it in the dialog's destructor - if you define it in the dialog as a `CBrush` object (not `CBrush*` or `HBRUSH`) this is not necessary, as C++ will call its destructor when the dialog object is destroyed. Alternatively, it can be created globally and never be destroyed, ie live throughout the app's lifetime (it's one single object after all) - the windows resource manager will destroy it automatically when the app exits.